# How to remove time from the watch face?

Tags: apple-watch

I have zero interest in knowing what time it is.
How can I remove the current time from the main screen on my Apple Watch?

Comment: Why wear a watch then...

Comment: Primarily for all-day fitness tracking and as an ECG monitor. Then possibly for certain notifications and controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t easily get rid of the clock display unless you enable Voiceover in accessibility settings and also turn on Screen Curtain.

If there is anything displayed,  Apple provides no face that hides or eliminates time. If you want to minimize the pixels devoted to the time display - choose Modular faces.

The most pixels you can devote to things other than time is the Infograph face, but it has large analog hands displayed, probably not what you want.

A jailbreak would be needed to make your own face or subtract / color the time to be the same color as the background and basically erase it visually.